# I keep getting a permissions issue related to CACHE when I set debug off in wger (open source workout manager)

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache2, open-source

I'm trying to set a personal wger app, and I've gotten to where I'm able to access and work on the site when I have the debug flag set to True. However, I'm trying to set it to False so I can use it without issues, but I keep getting the following error
`Exception Type: PermissionError at /en/dashboard Exception Value: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/CACHE' Raised during: wger.core.views.misc.dashboard Request information: USER: 20757882b35a40388f56e7aac0bf82`
I don't have much experience with Python, but even then, I don't see any settings for a cache directory in settings.py . I even added a cache directory in the root with no luck.
[image]

I'm attaching a screenshot of the directory permissions. I also have a very long stack trace, but I can't really see if it's got too much pertinent information, other than the error, but I can go ahead and post it if necessary (might need to edit it, since it's got a lot of security information.